# Android getDeclaredConstructors() behaving differently for Android 28 (Pie)

Tags: java, android, reflection, constructor

I know, this looks like a bad idea but my project has this line here:

```
val constructor = SQLiteQuery::class.java.declaredConstructors.first()
```

The class itself has one non public constructor but that is exactly the one I need for further work.

```
SQLiteQuery(SQLiteDatabase db, String query, CancellationSignal cancellationSignal) {
   super(db, query, null, cancellationSignal);
   mCancellationSignal = cancellationSignal;
}
```

It works fine when `targetSdkVersion 27` is set. However, the moment I set the `targetSdkVersion 28` this causes problems on Android 9. **The list of constructors is empty** (so not even private ones are included).

I can't find any changes in the API / documentation. The source code also still shows the above mentioned constructor.

**Question is: Why is this and how can I get the complete list of constructors?**

Comment: They're starting to restrict reflection to access normally-inaccessible members in the SDK: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/restrictions-non-sdk-interfaces.

Comment: Thank you, that is the answer I needed. Feel free to write a message so I can accept it!

Comment: Oh, it's cool. I didn't really solve anything for ya. Just pointed to some information. We'll call it a freebie. :-) Please feel free to post an answer yourself, if you like, or to delete this, if you'd rather. Thank you, though. I appreciate the offer. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so based on Mikes comment, the reason is some security "improvement" on Andriod side.

Beginning from Android 9 they restrict (even via Reflection) lots of Methods and fields.

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/restrictions-non-sdk-interfaces

So when you use your app, you may see some warnings in the LogCat. For us it was for instance this one:

```
Accessing hidden field Landroid/database/sqlite/SQLiteProgram;->mBindArgs:[Ljava/lang/Object; (light greylist, reflection)
```

It tells that the constructor we wanted was restricted (i.e. not available) which caused the list of constructors to return empty (and that caused the crash).

Google states the amount of restricted methods and fields as follows:

> The lists are approximately:
>
> whitelist (also known as SDK) ~= 74,000 methods and fields
>
> light-greylist ~= 11,000 methods and fields dark-greylist ~= 121,000
>
> methods and fields blacklist ~= 9,000 methods and fields

Be aware that it only "worked" (the crash came from the later usage of the empty return value, but the call itself wasn't throwing) because the method `light greylist` whereas it would throw exceptions if it were "darker".

**The easiest solution indeed is the target version to 27 (instead of 28) if you have only light grey warnings.** That "buys you time" until the next Android Version when they might restrict it further.
For throwing errors this probably isn't what you want because it may still crash!

Comment: Thanks so much! You saved me from going clinically insane!